# Center text in div if single line else display ellipsis

Tags: html, css

I need to display max two lines of text in a div, and if text exceeds two lines then display ellipses at the end of two line text.

```
+------------------------+
| Some text for test and |
| Some text for test ... |
+------------------------+
```

Also if text is only single line then, I need to display that single line in middle of div, left aligned. (below example shows three lines and text, but it should be two lines :) ).

```
+------------------------+
|                        |  
| Some text for test and |
|                        |  
+------------------------+
```

Currently I am using below code:

```css
.mainDiv {
  font-size: 10px;
  min-height: 10px;
  max-height: 20px;
  line-height: 10px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  some text for test
</div>
```

Using above code it works well in case if text has two or more than two lines. But if text is single line then it is not displayed in center of div, it is displayed at the top.

**Update**
The problem is when we combine both:
   1. Max 2 line ellipsis text in a div
   2. Single row text in middle of div

functionality together.

Comment: @GauravAggarwal the linked *duplicate* does not address the OP's centering condition

Comment: @GauravAggarwal the problem starts when you combine your both questions, ellipses and center single line text, so I have asked this question, and also I have seen these both questions before posting new question.

Comment: @GauravAggarwa Please check updated part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably wrap your `mainDiv` inside 2 divs with `display: table-cell` and `display: table` respectively. Then, `vertical-align: middle` on the cell.

You just need to set your outer-most `div` to your desired height.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pcmfmz80/)

```css
.mainDiv {
  font-size: 14px;
  min-height: 10px;
  max-height: 20px;
  line-height: 10px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="mainDiv">
      text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="mainDiv">
      text text text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```